# Transforming dict data into dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data stored like  this, how i can transform this, to a dataframe.

{"1":{"tabla":{"0":{"mun":"Aguascalientes","mun_vac":"4837"},"1":{"mun":"Asientos","mun_vac":"654"},"2":{"mun":"Calvillo","mun_vac":"290"},"3":{"mun":"Cos\u00edo","mun_vac":"211"},"4":{"mun":"El Llano","mun_vac":"227"},"5":{"mun":"Jes\u00fas Mar\u00eda","mun_vac":"342"},"6":{"mun":"Pabell\u00f3n de Arteaga","mun_vac":"345"},"7":{"mun":"Rinc\u00f3n de Romos","mun_vac":"211"}

Comment: What does your desired DataFrame look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want something like this?

```
x = {"1":{"tabla":{"0":{"mun":"Aguascalientes","mun_vac":"4837"},
                   "1":{"mun":"Asientos","mun_vac":"654"},
                   "2":{"mun":"Calvillo","mun_vac":"290"},
                   "3":{"mun":"Cos\u00edo","mun_vac":"211"},
                   "4":{"mun":"El Llano","mun_vac":"227"},
                   "5":{"mun":"Jes\u00fas Mar\u00eda","mun_vac":"342"},
                   "6":{"mun":"Pabell\u00f3n de Arteaga","mun_vac":"345"},
                   "7":{"mun":"Rinc\u00f3n de Romos","mun_vac":"211"}}}}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(x['1']['tabla'])
df
```

Output:

[image: Sample]